# Acces database from Google AppSheet in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-appsheet

When searching net and forums for this everything deals with how to use spreadsheet data in AppSheet. But I want to know how to do vice versa:

I have an AppSheet with data stored in databases. How can I access or import this data statically or better dynamically data from this in a Google spreadsheet? Is there st working like `=IMPORTRANGE(…)`? How do I address the db?

This would allow me to use better performing database tables than sheets for data storage.

Comment: this is the official documentation on `AppSheet`: [AppSheet Databases: Create and copy databases](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/12635312?hl=en), does this help?

Comment: @Twilight Thanks for the hint, but this doc also only explains the other way (sheet to db) or a static export.